# CSS Grid: Position grid items in specific column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a `ul` which in total contains `11` items.

I'm using `display: grid` in order to achieve a layout where the first column (of the two) contains `7` of the `li` elements.

I've tried to follow the [approach here](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/moving-css-grid-items/), by using `grid-template-areas`, but my `left` `li`'s seem to overlap each other.

In short, I'm looking to have first column (left) with `7` items, and second column (right) with `4`.

Demo:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "left right";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  min-width: 375px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.grid__item:nth-child(-n+7) {
  grid-area: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Right</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Right</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Right</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Right</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /* this */
  min-width: 375px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.grid__item {
  grid-column:2; /* and this */
}

.grid__item:nth-child(-n+7) {
  grid-column:1; /* and this */
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Left</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Right</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Right</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Right</li>
  <li class="grid__item">Right</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like this approach

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, why didn't the `grid-template-areas` approach work?

Comment: @Freddy template-areas are for specific area (row AND column) for each item. Here you only need to define the column and leave the row automatic